# Yii2 : Handling Assets For A custom theme

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have created a theme, its working file but its one problem is that assets file out of **theme** directory.

I create a theme in the following path

```
/var/www/html/project_name/themes/theme_name
```

And my theme file structure is

```
<theme_name>
    -layouts
        main.php
    -css
        style.css
    -js
        script.js
    -images
        logo.jpg
```

I put the all css, js file path in `assets/AppAssets.php`, So my `AppAssets.php` looks as

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@app/themes/bluehorse';
    public $css = [
        'css/style.css'

    ];
    public $js = [
        script.js
    ];
    public $depends = [
       'yii\web\YiiAsset',
       'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

And my **layout** file (e.g - `main.php`) looks like

```
<?php
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

AppAsset::register($this);
...................



?>
```

You can see I am use `AppAssets` as a my themes assets. But I don't want to use `AppAssets`. I want to create my own assets in  my theme. I want to put all css, js path in my won `assets` file that will be placed in my theme folder.  It's possible?? I need help of your.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your own assets in theme (exactly in view):

```
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
    $this->registerJsFile('@themes/theme_name/js/name.js', ['depends' => 'yii\web\YiiAsset']) ;
    $this->registerCssFile('@themes/theme_name/css/name.css' ) ;
```

can change layout in controller like:

```
public $layout = 'another_name_layout';
```

There are many way to provide change themes, one of this :

```
if ($layout = 'another_name_layout') {
$this->registerCssFile('@web/css/name.css' ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can insert your assets ( css and js ) in directory assests .
you must create a asset file like appAssets , add your custom css and js .
 be carefull "UrlPath" and "BasePath" must be your theme directory.

note !!! you must set following in your main layout:

```html
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?php $this->head() ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```